# Is the return of conventional deadlift to starting position actually just an RDL?

Tags: deadlifts

I am fairly certain they should be the same, but I have never read such a comparison being made on the internet. Could someone ascertain if my idea is right or wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're similar but not the same.

First off, most people don't lower the deadlift. They instead disengage the weight and essentially drop it with control. This is because most people can lift way more in the concentric (lifting) part of the lift, and disengaging is a safer way to put the weight back to the starting position.

In contrast, the RDL starts at the top so you would lift only a weight that you can carry safely.

Now if you do decide to lower the deadlift or you were to do something like a [floating deadlift](https://vimeo.com/717719721), then the two are very similar. The key difference is that with an RDL, your knees do not travel forward, and your shins stay vertical. This stretches out your glutes and hamstrings quite a bit more than the eccentric portion of the deadlift. This will also mean your shoulders will be way further out from your feet. You won't be able to lower the weight very far while maintaining a neutral spine position, so the range of motion is a lot shorter (unless you're fairly flexible). When lowering for a deadlift, you allow the knees to travel forward which allows you to lower the weight much deeper. Your shins won't be vertical. Your shoulders will be over your feet.